# Regex to allow numbers and digits but only one comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a task where the user should be able to edit the first line of an address field but they should only be able to use one comma but can put that one comma anywhere in the string.

I was wondering if there was a way that this could be done in JavaScript?

so far I have tried:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\&\-\,\.\/\'_ ]+$
```

But this regex allows me to enter multiple commas.

So I want the regex to allow the user to do this:

21, Tash Place N13 2IJ

or this:
,Tash Place 21 N13 2IJ

But not this:

21, Tash Place, N13, 2IJ

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yeah, probably. Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Did you tried?.

Comment: Yes there is...

Comment: this site http://rubular.com/ will help you build your own

Comment: What is "text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[-a-zA-Z0-9&.\/'_ ]*(?:,[-a-zA-Z0-9&.\/'_ ]*)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WRYKvZ/1).

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of string,
- `[-a-zA-Z0-9&.\/'_ ]*` - matches 0+ letters, digits or `-./'_` symbols, then
- `(?:,[-a-zA-Z0-9&.\/'_ ]*)?` - an optional sequence (1 or 0 occurrences) of:

  - `,`  - a comma (thus, only one is allowed)
  - `[-a-zA-Z0-9&.\/'_ ]*` - matches 0+ letters, digits or `-./'_` symbols, then
- `$` - end of string.

Another way is to add a `(?!(?:[^,]*,){2})` negative lookahead to your regex:

```
/^(?!(?:[^,]*,){2})[-a-zA-Z0-9&.\/',_ ]+$/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WRYKvZ/2)

The `(?!(?:[^,]*,){2})` lookahead will fail the match if there are 2 sequences of 0+ chars other than `,` and then a `,` in the string.